# How can I authorize AWS Cognito user when using In-app Purchase on IOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, react-native, in-app-purchase

I'm testing In-app Purchase (IAP) in my App with IOS's sandbox tester.
My app is using AWS Cognito to signup and login.

Step 1: **User A** successfully paid for an auto-renewable subscription.

Step 2: **User B** login to the App with the same IOS device.

Actual Result: **User B** is using the subscription that paid by **user A**.

I expect that **User B** cannot using the subscription that **User A** has paid.

How I can do that? Thanks in advance!